# Access a JavaScript variable from PHP link

Tags: php, javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and PHP.  I need to get some variables from a PHP link into my JavaScript.  I need to access `a1`, a text variable (**Edit: string**) as well as `a2` and `a3`, two `int` variables from `myfile.php`.  Can anyone give me an example using three variables?

Comment: Generally JavaScript and PHP don't talk to each other.  Your PHP code can emit JavaScript to the page, and your JavaScript code can make an AJAX call to PHP, so there are options available.  Can you provide more information?  Maybe show some code in an attempt to do what you think would make sense and explain how it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean "from a php link"?

Comment: from a php file on the server

Comment: Can you please give us a proper example?

Comment: i need to acces the php file. that file looks in a database and return 3 variables from that to a js code

Comment: @user1044037: Are the variables available during the page request?  You can have your PHP script include the other script and call a function on it, get the results, and write them to the page where the JavaScript code can use them.  If the values aren't available until later in the page's life then the JavaScript would need to make an AJAX call to a PHP script which would do the same thing I just described, but would write the values to a JSON response instead of to a web page.  Please provide a code sample to clarify how you envision this working.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understood you, but I think you need this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = <?echo $x;?>;
var y = <?echo $y;?>;
var myString = <?echo $my_string;?>;
</script>
```

And if you want to access your php file more than one time you need to use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

If you dont understand AJAX you can do it easier way to do that is jquery [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), post, ect. function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
    echo "<script>"
    echo "alert(eval('" + $_GET["a1"] + "'));";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

Comment: @user1044037: Can your PHP file just include that other file and call the function(s) that return(s) the values?

Comment: A link doesn't access JS variable. A link can only give parameter(s) either to server or client side. Btw, what is 'PHP link'?

Answer (score 0):

Your php code could return a json object with the correct headers.

You PHP file would look something like:

```
<?php 
// set correct headers
header('Content-type: application/javascript'); 

// create array of data
$data = array(
  'a1' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
  'a2' => 123456789,
  'a3' => 987654321  
);

?>
window.Content = window.Content || {};
window.Content.data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

And then you could get the data in your html like this:

```
<script src="/YourPhpFile.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(window.Content.data);
</script>
```

Comment: thanx, but how can i acces the variables from console?

Comment: The console.log is a debugging tool that prints the specified variable to the, you guessed it, the console. You can access your variables like this: window.Content.data.a1; window.Content.data.a2; window.Content.data.a3;

Comment: This is so that the browser interprets /YourPhpFile.php as javascript (it's just good practice in reality)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, still kind of unsure what you're trying to accomplish. But if you `require_once()` the file you need, its resources will become available in the file you called it from.

myFile.php

```
<?php
$x = 1;
$y = 2;
$z = "hello nick";
?>
```

otherFile.php

```
require_once("/myFile.php");

<body>
<div id="divjs"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('divjs').innerHTML = '<?php echo "x: $x<br/>y: $y<br/>z: $z<br/>"; ?>';
</script>
</body>
```